# Expose postgres server to public network with an intermediate server

Tags: ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, postgresql

I have a postgres server (but it could be any service, I suppose) running in local a network and a server (AWS EC2 instance) that I'd like to use as an intermediary to access the database.

So far, I've managed to make a reverse ssh tunnel from the local server to the intermediary:

```
autossh -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -fnN -R 5432:localhost:5432 user@intermedite-host
```

I can already access the database from my laptop if I do a "forward" tunnel to the server, and then just connect to my `localhost:5432` (in the laptop).

However, what I'd like to do is to have the database public as if it were running in the intermediary server, connecting to it with just `intermedite-host:5432`.

So far, I've played around with another ssh tunnel only inside `intermedite-host` and with `iptables`. But I'm out of my depth and can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do what you ask (below) but I wonder if it's really the right thing in your case.

The canonical way to do what you are looking for in AWS is to use AWS features rather than a Linux host forwarding ports.  This would usually be either:

- setup the EC2 Instance running your service (PostgreSQL) with its own public IP address. You can use security groups to limit public access down to only the one port (5432).
- or setup an [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in AWS and forward port 5432 to your EC2 machine there.

---

#### Configuring with stunnel

Since you are going to expose this to the public internet you might consider using making your intermediate machine an SSL gateway.  You could setup [stunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stunnel) to serve an SSL encrypted port 5432 to the internet and forward the unencrypted side to your PostgreSQL server.

---

#### Configuring with IP tables

To do this under Linux you can setup the intermediate machine as a NAT gateway.  But challenge is making sure the PostgreSQL understands correctly what to do with the outbound traffic (back to the clients).  You need to either:

- Configure your PostgreSQL server to route all outbound traffic (port 5432) to public IP addresses via your intermediate server
- Configure your intermediate server with two NATs: One public side, one private side.  That way PostgreSQL will always see your intermediate server talking to it, and.

*I don't have the right commands to do this to hand so will come back to edit them in later.*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. After some more search after posting the question, I ended up finding the option `GatewayPorts no` in `sshd_config` file and setting it to `yes`. That did the trick for me. I don't know whether I should post that as an answer, though.

Comment: @mbtg It would be good to for future readers